# AT+CNBP command for SIM8202G-M2 cellular module

Tags: serial, communication, at-commands

I've been trying to setup this module on CM4 rasberry device. So far I managed to get it setup to boot with the system, the main issue here it only finds LTE network.

I used AT commands in order to figure what's the preferred mode (AT+CNMP=?), which was automatic. I set it to LTE+NR5G. Still picking only LTE (4G). I decided to change it to NR5G only. It returned this error:

> [05-08_15:47:04:872] requestBaseBandVersion

> MPSS.HI.2.0.3-00269-SDX55_CPEALL_PACK-1  1  [Aug 03 2021 13:00:00]

> [05-08_15:47:05:000] requestGetSIMStatus SIMStatus: SIM_ABSENT

> [05-08_15:47:05:064] requestGetProfile[1](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/1/17/SIM8200_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.00.01_0515.pdf) ///0 [05-08_15:47:05:128]

> requestRegistrationState2 MCC: 0, MNC: 0, PS: Detached, DataCap:

> UNKNOW [05-08_15:47:05:192] requestQueryDataCall IPv4ConnectionStatus:

> DISCONNECTED [05-08_15:47:05:320] requestRegistrationState2 MCC: 0,

> MNC: 0, PS: Detached, DataCap: UNKNOW [05-08_15:47:10:439]

> requestRegistrationState2 MCC: 0, MNC: 0, PS: Detached, DataCap:

> UNKNOW

I scooped up the manual [(link)](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/1/17/SIM8200_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.00.01_0515.pdf) at page 82, 83, 84, 85 & 86. Yet I couldn't change the frequency of n78 band (the 5G band of my ISP). I used AT+CNBP command and received this response:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/PhaxhAA.jpg]

I tried my best to change the frequencies of whatever is showing above, but yet to no luck. I even tried to use the command provided by Waveshare in case 5G network isn't connected but it always returned "Error":

> AT+CNBP? //(Can copy the frequency band to Notepad) Backup frequency

> AT + CNBP = 0x100600000FC00000,0X000000000000000046000001E2000908DD,0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

> AT+CNMP=71 // Fixed 5G

This still didn't work yet. 5G works in the sim card I'm using on my iPhone 13. Goes at full speed. Yet for some reason this module fails to lock on 5G network. I tried to contact WaveShare but it looks like they ignored my support tickets or themselves couldn't figure it out.

I double checked the n78 band here against the SA bands the device supports. Please help me to figure this thing out.

Edit: Please check first image, you can see the module can see 2 carriers, only with LTE bands.

Comment: Is this a problem: "requestGetSIMStatus SIMStatus: SIM_ABSENT"?

Comment: @JRE Not a problem. I applied (NR5G only) preferred mode. Shows SIM_READY. Yet no network is dectected.

Comment: @WildStar did you solve your problem? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: SIMCOM weren’t helpful. WaveShare helped me with activating EUTRAN network but so far no NR5G. I settled for EUTRAN network configuration which helped with speed and latency. In the future I’ll be switching do Qualcomm devices as their support is better. 

I highly suspect my telecom (Etisalar or TDRA) blocking certain devices that aren’t mobile phones. Tried to contact them. They were more useless cuz they out source their projects to overseas cheap companies instead of employing real engineers.

Comment: Is there any way to mimic mobile phones via AT commands ? or is that illegal , or any other way